# Emacs function on set of files

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way implemented in Emacs to apply a function on a set of files? (Or, if not, do you know of such an extension?)

For example, if you have a project in a directory (say, scripts to compile and run, the source, and an XML database). You want to run this function on all those files, one by one:

```
(defun indent-buffer ()
  "Indent the whole buffer according to indent-region-function."
  (interactive)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)) )
```

What complicates the picture at least to some degree, although certainly not impossible, is that Emacs must be in the correct mode to execute such a function sensibly.

The coolest interface would be to use Emacs as a server, and then send the command, and the file list, as arguments.

Second best if it could be done in Dired.

Comment: For sample code that does similar, look at `bytecomp.el` implementing the functions `byte-compile-file` and `byte-recompile-directory`
which performs the following  
"Recompile every `.el' file in DIRECTORY that needs recompilation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In batch mode, loop over the arguments.

```
emacs --batch -l cl --eval '
  (dolist (filename command-line-args-left)
    (find-file filename)
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer))'
```

From dired, use the `dired-map-over-marks` macro from `dired.el` or the `dired-map-over-marks-check` function from `dired-aux.el`.

```
(dired-map-over-marks-check indent-buffer nil 'indent)
```

Comment: The batch mode code works great, only, I had to remove the `-1` option, and that's not in my `man emacs`, either?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg I have no idea where that `-1` crept in from.